How to install "make" using Chromebook or online source? (Linux is not able to be activated on Chromebook)
I'm asking this because i'm trying to complete this tutorial: https://marcnu.github.io/2016-09-10/How-to-install-Netgear-A6100-USB-Wifi-adapter-on-Ubuntu-16.04/ It needs make to create the driver, I have no Ethernet to connect. Please help, because I'm reviving a old Dell Inspiron 530S. I'm using Ubuntu 24.04 LTS Desktop as my current version on my Dell. Any help soon would be appreciated, also again I'm on Chromebook.

I would like to have a answer soon, would be greatly appreciated!

I am using the latest Ubuntu version as of now, (24.04)

That should help with more details, if anything else is needed please ask!
